# PHP strange behavior in function nl2br

Tags: php, function, behavior

I was dealing with refactoring of my small web app. all night. Today when I started testing, first bug what I found was problem with system PHP function `nl2br()`.

On my localhost I have PHP version **5.2.9** and as I see on [PHP site](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) from version **4.0.5** `nl2br()` is *XHTML* compliant.

Then I absolutely don't understand why does my `nl2br()` return `<br>` without second argument set to false instead of `<br />`.

Here is my method where I found this bug:

```
public function eliminateTags($msg) {
    $setBrakes = nl2br($msg);
    $decodeHTML = htmlspecialchars_decode($setBrakes);

    # Check PHP version
    if((int)version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '4.0.5') == 1) {
        $withoutTags = strip_tags($decodeHTML, '<br />');
    } else {
        $withoutTags = strip_tags($decodeHTML, '<br>');
    }

    return $withoutTags;
}
```

Comment: I can't say I can reproduce this with the latest PHP 5.2 The changelog says nothing about this. Do you have a script that reproduces this problem?

Comment: How are you checking the br tags? 
# Are you using Firebug (or wathever similar tool)? 
# are you looking into a file generated by your script?
# are you checking the strings generated by your script?

Comment: It uses `<br />` by default for me, with 5.3.2.

Comment: php 5.2.12-pl0-gentoo on ideone.com works fine too

Comment: Works as expected (`<br />`) on PHP 5.3.1 on Windows.

Comment: @Pekka could you try out my method/function?

Comment: `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(nl2br("sdf<that/>&lt;that/&gt;sdf\nsfdsf")), "<br>")` gives the expected result on the latest 5.2 RC

Comment: @Eugene I tried your function, `nl2br` consistently gives me `<br />`. You are 10000% sure that the problem is with `nl2br` and not `strip_tags`?

Comment: @Eugene There have been some changes in strip_tags, in principle none should cause your problem, but there may have been some bug that was fixed as a side effect. Could you write here what's the output of `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(nl2br("sdf<that/>&lt;that/&gt;sdf\nsfdsf")), "<br>")` ?

Comment: That is pretty strange. I commented out the conditional part and left only two first lines. Now it works fine. By fine I mean it placed `<br />`. Damn, how I hate to apologize.

But then there must be a problem with strip_tags, no?

Comment: @Eugene: I believe I found your problem, check my edit.

Comment: @Artefacto it gave `sdfsdf<br />sfdsf`, but if I switch `&lt;` and `&gt;`the return is strange. It deletes all that `sdf\nsfdsf` part. Shouldn't strip_tags eliminate only fully opened and closed tags? Since, that would be only opened `<sdf\nsfdsf`.

Comment: @Anax Nop, he's only using "<br />" for versions lower than 4.0.5.

Comment: @Eug I guess it deletes everything after a tag that's never complete (considers it part of the tag).

Comment: @Eugene Again, I can't say I can reproduce it. http://codepad.viper-7.com/MyfqrC (I assumed you were using Anax's solution). Note: response to subsequently delete comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish with this function. First of all you insert HTML breaks in every new line and then you strip all tags except the breaks.

Wouldn't it be more sensible to strip the tags first and then insert the HTML line breaks?

```
public function eliminateTags($msg) {
    $decodeHTML = htmlspecialchars_decode($msg);
    $withoutTags = strip_tags($decodeHTML);
    $setBreaks = nl2br($withoutTags);

    return $setBreaks;
}
```

**Edit:**

Apparently you are not using `strip_tags()` correctly. You need to ask PHP which tag to exclude, which is `<br>`, not `<br />`. Asking PHP to exclude`<br />` is like asking to exclude, say, `<p></p>` which won't work.

Which in turn means you must not check for a PHP version - `strip_tags()` will work as is in all versions.

Comment: Okey, that worked out. But was could be the problem when I tried the other way around? I wanted to make method for eliminating unwanted tags. For exmaple what would happen if I wrote `<script>alert();</script>`, but using this method it will return `alret();`.

Comment: @Eugene strip_tags has an "allowed tags" parameter.

Comment: @Pekka yes and I used it, didn't I? And problem still came up.

Comment: @Artefacto: Indeed I did not solve the problem. Instead I chose to eliminate it. Nevertheless I believe I found what was causing the bug as well.

Comment: @Anax yep, I guess you did. Now it works as I planed, by the way good tip about the recognition of the tag, since there is no mentioning of it.

Comment: @Anax No, you didn't. The code path that uses `"<br />" as an argument is never executed.

Comment: @Anax Sorry, you're right, that's the code path that is executed, not the correct one. Still, I cannot reproduce the bug when "<br />" is used as an argument (it simply strips the `<br />` anyway).

Comment: @Anax your code is much better for what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you very much. Also thank you for the tip about difference in `<br>` and `<br />` as argument in function `strip_tags`.